# Return type from specs2 helper method

Tags: scala, specs2

Let's assume I write a helper method, that accepts some test code.

```
def testWithPrintln(test: => A):A = {
    println("I'm happy and testing")
    test
}
```

What should be the `A` type be? What is the right one? I'm browsing the `specs2` api and there are numerous similar looking types: `AsResult[_]`, `Result`, `MatchResult[_]`, I'm confused what to use.

Comment: The same as the return type of your test method, or Any if you don't know / care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to elaborate on @cmbaxter's answer.

In specs2 the body of an `Example` needs to be evaluated as a `Result`, that is either a `Success` or `Failure` or `Error` or `Skipped` or `Pending`. In order to provide enough flexibility, the body of an `Example` will accept *any* type `T` that can be transformed to a `Result` provided that an instance of `AsResult[T]` is in (the implicit) scope.

There are instances of `AsResult` for various types:

- `Boolean`: this makes `true` being a `Success` and `false` being a `failure`
- `Result` itself, just returning the value
- `MatchResult[T]`: a `MatchResult` is the result of a matcher execution. This is the result of 
  expressions such as `1 must beEqualTo(1)`
- `org.scalacheck.Prop` to execute a ScalaCheck property in an example

In your example, the test helper will work fine if you implement it like this:

```
// if `a: A` is acceptable as the body of an example
// you can use testWithPrintln(a) in your example
def testWithPrintln[A : AsResult](a: A): A = {
  println(a)
  a
}
```

Note however that the helper you are looking for might already exist in specs2. You can use the `.pp` method to "print and pass" any value:

```
// has type MatchResult[Int]
(1 must_== 1).pp
```

Also you can add more verbose messages to your expectations:

```
 // will print "this is not correct because 1 is not equal to 2"
 "this is correct" ==> { 1 must_== 2 }

 // will print "the number of elements: 1 is not greater than 2
 val n = 1
 n aka "the number of elements" must be_>(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `org.specs2.execute.Result`.  I believe this quick example demonstrates what you were going for:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.execute.Result

class PrintTest extends Specification{

  "A request to do something" should{
    "succeed like this" in testWithPrintln{
      "foo" mustEqual "foo"            
    }
    "also succeed like this" in {
      testWithPrintln{
        "foo" mustEqual "foo"            
      }
    }
  }

  def testWithPrintln(test: => Result) {
      println("I'm happy and testing")
      test
  }  
}
```

I believe that the `AsResult` type is used in implicit conversions between basic types (like Boolean) that are not themselves `Result`s but can be converted to a `Result`.  If you look at the javadoc comment for `AsResult` it states:

```
Typeclass trait for anything that can be transformed to a Result
```

As for `MatchResult`, I believe this is used when performing matching on things like params when using stubbing via Mockito.  I've used `MatchResult` a few times explicitly when defining custom matchers for params in my mock stubbing.

Comment: And do you know, what is the difference between the `Result` and the other ones? I also edited the question: the return type to make it clearer.